# Drone.io instead of Travis

Tags: docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen that for most developers, Indigo branches and future Jade have been troubling, given that Travis still only supports ubuntu 12.04 (and therefore up to Hydro). There have been long talks on github about this functionality over a number of repos and still, there is no official date when 14.04 will be supported on Travis and how that support will be provided.

On the other hand, drone.io uses docker in the build environment which might be a generic solution for all ros distros. Are there drawbacks to moving CI builds to docker (with drone.io)? Am I not considering something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210507/drone.io-instead-of-travis/) by [Progtologist](https://answers.ros.org/users/11081/progtologist/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2015-06-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [carlosjoserg](https://answers.ros.org/users/4768/carlosjoserg/) on 2015-06-23**:
I'm interested in this as well. I haven't been able to configure a build, since the default env is 12.04 in drone.io as well.

**Comment by [carlosjoserg](https://answers.ros.org/users/4768/carlosjoserg/) on 2015-06-23**:
http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-core-differences-between-Travis-CI-and-drone-io

**Comment by [Progtologist](https://answers.ros.org/users/11081/progtologist/) on 2015-06-23**:
I will try to make a build in the next days. Depending on the results I will respond to my own question for future reference!

**Comment by [Progtologist](https://answers.ros.org/users/11081/progtologist/) on 2015-08-13**:
Hello Stefan,
Travis has also moved to docker [link here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/), so moving everything to drone.io seems overkill. I want to put together some scripts for docker based CI, but I have not yet found the time to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just came across this question after posting my own (http://answers.ros.org/question/215724/travis-ci-with-1404indigo-andor-alternatives/). I'm also looking for a good CI solution, so if there are any updates I´d be interested :)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently open source Shadow Robot's build tools support Travis CI, Shippable, Circle CI, Semaphore etc.

This is Docker based solution.
The main idea is to be  CI server agnostic and set up build process for less than 15 minutes.
There is possibility to choose what do you want to run e.g. unit tests, code coverage, roslint checks.

More information and links to documentation can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/CIs#Shadow_Robot.27s_Build_Tools)

---

Originally posted by [Andriy Petlovanyy](https://answers.ros.org/users/25006/andriy-petlovanyy/) with karma: 21 on 2015-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1